# Parsing HaarCascade XML with Accord.NET-The ReadElementContentAsString method is not supported on node type None

Tags: xml, opencv, face-detection, biometrics, accord.net

Im trying to detect upperbody using Accord.NET.It works for facial detection using the inbuilt cascade for Face.But when i try to load the OpenCV upper body HaarCasecade using

```
 HaarCascade cascade = HaarCascade.FromXml(@"C:\Users\me\Desktop\haarcascade_upperbody.xml");
```

i keep getting

```
The ReadElementContentAsString method is not supported on node type None. Line 28134, position 18.
```

The XML is very large so please take a look here https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/data/haarcascades/haarcascade_upperbody.xml

Answer (score 2):

Currently, *Accord.NET Framework* only supports the **old** Open CV *Haar Cascade* XML format, see for example [this](https://github.com/accord-net/framework/issues/83) and [this](https://github.com/accord-net/framework/issues/118) issue on Github.

You can access the older formatted *Haar Cascade* files if you go to an old enough commit of the *Open CV* repository, for example [the commit before the format upgrade](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/tree/fdf1996e2ebf25cbc185250404aa9e96d5566302/data/haarcascades).